# pairwise distance and residual calculation optimization

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy

I have a code for calculating the pairwise distances and the residuals of my data (X, Y, Z). Data is quite large (average of 7000 rows) and so my interest is code efficiency. My initial code is

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import, numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

data = pd.read_excel(file_path)
data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float)
npoints, cols = data.shape

pwdistance = np.zeros((npoints, npoints))
pwresidual = np.zeros((npoints, npoints))
for i in range(npoints):
    for j in range(npoints):
        pwdistance[i][j] = np.sqrt((data[:,0][i]-data[:,0][j])**2 + (data[:,1][i]-data[:,1][j])**2)
        pwresidual[i][j] = (data[:,2][i]-data[:,2][j])**2
```

With the `pwdistance`, I changed it to the following below which works extremely good.

```
pwdistance = squareform(pdist(data[:,:2]))
```

Is there a pythonic way of calculating my `pwresidual`, so I do not need to use a loop and to enable my code to run faster?

Comment: You could use `np.hypot` instead of `np.sqrt` and `**2`

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo It seems OP is asking to get/optimize `pwresidual`. I got it confused the first time around too :)

Comment: @Divakar That's why I made a comment instead of an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to extend dimensions of the second column slice of `data` to form a `2D` array and subtracting the `1D` slice  itself from it. These subtractions would be performed in a vectorized manner following the rules of [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Thus, simply do -

```
pwresidual = (data[:,2,None] - data[:,2])**2
```

Step-by-step run -

```
In [132]: data[:,2,None].shape # Slice extended to a 2D array
Out[132]: (4, 1)

In [133]: data[:,2].shape # Slice as 1D array
Out[133]: (4,)

In [134]: data[:,2,None] - data[:,2] # Subtractions with broadcasting
Out[134]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.67791602,  0.13298141,  0.61579315],
       [-0.67791602,  0.        , -0.54493461, -0.06212288],
       [-0.13298141,  0.54493461,  0.        ,  0.48281174],
       [-0.61579315,  0.06212288, -0.48281174,  0.        ]])

In [137]: (data[:,2,None] - data[:,2]).shape # Verify output shape
Out[137]: (4, 4)

In [138]: (data[:,2,None] - data[:,2])**2 # Finally elementwise square
Out[138]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.45957013,  0.01768406,  0.3792012 ],
       [ 0.45957013,  0.        ,  0.29695373,  0.00385925],
       [ 0.01768406,  0.29695373,  0.        ,  0.23310717],
       [ 0.3792012 ,  0.00385925,  0.23310717,  0.        ]])
```